# Having problems retrieving response from a servlet in J2ME

Tags: java, servlets, java-me

I am trying to retreive a response from a servlet to a midlet using the code below

```
public String receiveData() {
        HttpConnection connection = null;
        String url = "http://localhost:8084/MCastServer/Create";
        DataInputStream is = null;
        OutputStream os = null;
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String res = null;
        try {
            connection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);
            connection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
            connection.setRequestProperty("IF-Modified-Since", "20 Jan 2001 16:19:14 GMT");
            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Profile/MIDP-2.0 Confirguration/CLDC-1.0");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-CA");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            os = connection.openOutputStream();
            is = connection.openDataInputStream();
            System.out.println(url);
            int ch = 0;
            while ((ch = is.read()) == -1) {
                stringBuffer.append((char) ch);
                System.out.println(stringBuffer);
            }
            res = stringBuffer.toString();
            System.out.println(res);
            //ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } finally {
            try {
                if (is != null) {
                    is.close();
                }
                if (os != null) {
                    os.close();
                }
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.close();

                }
                //display.setCurrent(textBox);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        }
        return res;
    }
```

But it keeps returning a null output. I have searched and tried various means but it still returns the same.
Below is the Servlet which I wrote

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String groupNames = "SELECT phone_group_name FROM phone_group_name";
        InteractToDB dbCall = new InteractToDB("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dbCall.connect("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mcast", "postgres", "mimi");
        out.print(dbCall.getNames());
        System.out.println(dbCall.getNames() + " call");
        try {

        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: where are you passing the query groupNames for execution ? What do you see in the log files in the server ? are you able to see the output for System.out.println(dbCall.getNames() + " call");

Comment: do you get any output if you execute your servlet from the browser?

Comment: Yes. I can see an output from System.out.println.. and on the browser.

Comment: I get to have the problem when I connect to a midlet.

Comment: What's that HTTPConnection doing?  Shouldn't the client be sending an HTTP request to the servlet and receiving the response?  Why does the servlet make a connection?

Answer (score 2):

You have an empty catch block - that's not a good idea.  You should print the stack trace at minimum.

I also think it's a terrible idea to put database code in a servlet.  I'd write an interface-based POJO, test out the code thoroughly without the servlet, and then call its methods in the servlet.  It decomposes the problem into smaller ones and helps your unit testing efforts.

Why are you creating a connection per request?  Why aren't you using a connection pool to amortize the cost of creating connections?

Why are you hard-wiring your information in plain text in the class?  What happens if `dbCall` is null?  What if a `SQLException` is thrown?

The more I look at this code, the worst it gets.  I'd better stop now.